# How do I add a class to this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I add a class to this? `<%= image_tag(event.actor.profile.photo.url(:tiny)) %>`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `image_tag`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= image_tag(event.actor.profile.photo.url(:tiny), :class => "foo") %>
```

Comment: ahh i was adding the class after the second `)`